# storing average of some columns in a new column in R

Tags: r

I have a data set of gene expressions in R as follows:

```
> head(sheet2)
  Gene.symbol log2FoldChange pvalue padj BEC141A BEC142A BEC167A BEC191A BEC199A TuBEC46A
1        SAA1          -6.37      0    0   64.00    2.00   56.00   18.00   21.00  8779.92
2     ADAMTS9          -4.58      0    0   21.00   23.00   50.00   16.00   11.00   223.00
3       TENM2          -5.24      0    0  139.00  147.00   51.00   10.00   45.00  2978.00
4        NRP2          -2.74      0    0  462.00  468.00 1008.00  134.00  233.00  3021.00
5        DPP4          -5.67      0    0   14.00   32.00    3.00    8.00    9.00   374.00
6       ZBTB1          -1.02      0    0  376.63  502.95  379.24  303.57  353.64   775.71
  TuBEC58A TuBEC60A TuBEC81A
1  1682.37   624.12    64.00
2  2202.00   234.00    30.00
3 10029.00   108.00   157.00
4  6621.00  2182.00  1802.00
5  2708.00    23.00     6.00
6  1304.89   697.78   792.81
```

I want to create the average and standard deviation for BEC and TuBEC in 4 different column for each row. I created the following loop for it:

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(sheet2)){
  sheet2$BECaverages <-  colMeans(sheet2[i, c(5:9)])
}
for (i in 1:nrow(sheet2)){
  sheet2$TuBECaverage <-  colMeans(sheet2[i, c(10:13)])
}
#>    Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "TuBECaverage", value = c(TuBEC46A = 8779.92,  : 
#>    replacement has 4 rows, data has 35
```

This loop gives an error for the second column I'm trying to create. Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
sheet2 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    BECmu = mean(c_across(matches("^BEC[0-9]"))),
    BECsigma = sd(c_across(matches("^BEC[0-9]"))), 
    TuBECmu = mean(c_across(matches("^TuBEC[0-9]"))), 
    TuBECsigma = sd(c_across(matches("^TuBEC[0-9]")))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 6 x 17
#   Gene.symbol log2FoldChange pvalue  padj BEC141A BEC142A BEC167A BEC191A BEC199A TuBEC46A TuBEC58A TuBEC60A TuBEC81A BECmu BECsigma TuBECmu TuBECsigma
#   <chr>                <dbl>  <int> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 SAA1                 -6.37      0     0     64       2      56      18      21     8780.    1682.     624.      64   32.2     26.5   2788.      4051.
# 2 ADAMTS9              -4.58      0     0     21      23      50      16      11      223     2202      234       30   24.2     15.2    672.      1024.
# 3 TENM2                -5.24      0     0    139     147      51      10      45     2978    10029      108      157   78.4     61.1   3318       4671.
# 4 NRP2                 -2.74      0     0    462     468    1008     134     233     3021     6621     2182     1802  461      338.    3406.      2203.
# 5 DPP4                 -5.67      0     0     14      32       3       8       9      374     2708       23        6   13.2     11.2    778.      1298.
# 6 ZBTB1                -1.02      0     0    377.    503.    379.    304.    354.     776.    1305.     698.     793. 383.      73.5    893.       278.
```

Note: if we instead use `starts_with("BEC")` (like I did at first), then the calculation of `BECmu` is correct, but then `BECsigma` mistakenly uses `BECmu` in its calculation of standard deviation, which is not what we want. I get around that by making sure we only use columns that are `BEC` followed by a number, what I'm inferring is a safe pattern given your data. If not, there are perhaps other ways to exclude `BECmu` from that, including creating a variable that does not *start* with `BEC` (at least initially ... it can be renamed later).

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(sheet2)[, c("BECmu", "BECsigma") := .(mean(unlist(.SD)), sd(unlist(.SD))), 
    .SDcols = patterns("^BEC"), by = seq_len(nrow(sheet2))
  ][, c("TuBECmu", "TuBECsigma") := .(mean(unlist(.SD)), sd(unlist(.SD))),
    .SDcols = patterns("^TuBEC"), by = seq_len(nrow(sheet2))][]
#    Gene.symbol log2FoldChange pvalue  padj BEC141A BEC142A BEC167A BEC191A BEC199A TuBEC46A TuBEC58A TuBEC60A TuBEC81A   BECmu  BECsigma   TuBECmu TuBECsigma
#         <char>          <num>  <int> <int>   <num>   <num>   <num>   <num>   <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>    <num>   <num>     <num>     <num>      <num>
# 1:        SAA1          -6.37      0     0   64.00    2.00   56.00   18.00   21.00  8779.92  1682.37   624.12    64.00  32.200  26.53677 2787.6025  4050.8466
# 2:     ADAMTS9          -4.58      0     0   21.00   23.00   50.00   16.00   11.00   223.00  2202.00   234.00    30.00  24.200  15.15586  672.2500  1024.1271
# 3:       TENM2          -5.24      0     0  139.00  147.00   51.00   10.00   45.00  2978.00 10029.00   108.00   157.00  78.400  61.08028 3318.0000  4670.8009
# 4:        NRP2          -2.74      0     0  462.00  468.00 1008.00  134.00  233.00  3021.00  6621.00  2182.00  1802.00 461.000 338.44202 3406.5000  2202.6833
# 5:        DPP4          -5.67      0     0   14.00   32.00    3.00    8.00    9.00   374.00  2708.00    23.00     6.00  13.200  11.21160  777.7500  1297.9631
# 6:       ZBTB1          -1.02      0     0  376.63  502.95  379.24  303.57  353.64   775.71  1304.89   697.78   792.81 383.206  73.50789  892.7975   277.8243
```

### base R

(Though this doesn't really *feel* awesome.)

```r
sheet2 <- cbind(sheet2, t(apply(subset(sheet2, select = grepl("^BEC", colnames(sheet2))), 1, function(z) c(BECmu = mean(z), BECsigma = sd(z)))))
sheet2 <- cbind(sheet2, t(apply(subset(sheet2, select = grepl("^TuBEC", colnames(sheet2))), 1, function(z) c(TuBECmu = mean(z), TuBECsigma = sd(z)))))
sheet2
#   Gene.symbol log2FoldChange pvalue padj BEC141A BEC142A BEC167A BEC191A BEC199A TuBEC46A TuBEC58A TuBEC60A TuBEC81A   BECmu  BECsigma   TuBECmu TuBECsigma
# 1        SAA1          -6.37      0    0   64.00    2.00   56.00   18.00   21.00  8779.92  1682.37   624.12    64.00  32.200  26.53677 2787.6025  4050.8466
# 2     ADAMTS9          -4.58      0    0   21.00   23.00   50.00   16.00   11.00   223.00  2202.00   234.00    30.00  24.200  15.15586  672.2500  1024.1271
# 3       TENM2          -5.24      0    0  139.00  147.00   51.00   10.00   45.00  2978.00 10029.00   108.00   157.00  78.400  61.08028 3318.0000  4670.8009
# 4        NRP2          -2.74      0    0  462.00  468.00 1008.00  134.00  233.00  3021.00  6621.00  2182.00  1802.00 461.000 338.44202 3406.5000  2202.6833
# 5        DPP4          -5.67      0    0   14.00   32.00    3.00    8.00    9.00   374.00  2708.00    23.00     6.00  13.200  11.21160  777.7500  1297.9631
# 6       ZBTB1          -1.02      0    0  376.63  502.95  379.24  303.57  353.64   775.71  1304.89   697.78   792.81 383.206  73.50789  892.7975   277.8243
```

We could have used `rowMeans` for the `*mu` values, but there is not an immediate `rowSDs` ... it's easy enough to write that, but I'd likely start with `apply(x, 1, sd)`, which is effectively what I'm doing here anyway.

The use of `apply(sheet2, 1, ..)` returns a `matrix` with 2 *rows* (not columns), so I `t`ranspose it to a 2-column return. It's still a matrix, but by using `cbind` where the first argument is `sheet2` (a `data.frame`), the second argument is converted into frame columns, so "it works".

---

Data

```r
sheet2 <- structure(list(Gene.symbol = c("SAA1", "ADAMTS9", "TENM2", "NRP2", "DPP4", "ZBTB1"), log2FoldChange = c(-6.37, -4.58, -5.24, -2.74, -5.67, -1.02), pvalue = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), padj = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BEC141A = c(64, 21, 139, 462, 14, 376.63), BEC142A = c(2, 23, 147, 468, 32, 502.95), BEC167A = c(56, 50, 51, 1008, 3, 379.24), BEC191A = c(18, 16, 10, 134, 8, 303.57), BEC199A = c(21, 11, 45, 233, 9, 353.64), TuBEC46A = c(8779.92, 223, 2978, 3021, 374, 775.71), TuBEC58A = c(1682.37,  2202, 10029, 6621, 2708, 1304.89), TuBEC60A = c(624.12, 234, 108, 2182, 23, 697.78), TuBEC81A = c(64, 30, 157, 1802, 6, 792.81)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the `sheet2` dataframe, but I think this works:

```r
sheet2 %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
        BECaverages = colMeans(dplyr::select(sheet2, dplyr::starts_with('BEC')))
        TuBECaverage = colMeans(dplyr::select(sheet2, dplyr::starts_with('TuBEC')))
    )
```

Comment: Your code is both a syntax error (missing a comma) and errs with `\`BECaverages\` must be size 6 or 1, not 5.` when used with valid-looking data.